# doesn't add width to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### HTML

```
<div class="ratingInfo">
    <div class="review-rating">5.0 </div>
    <div class="stars1"></div>
</div>

<div class="ratingInfo">
    <div class="review-rating">4.0 </div>
    <div class="stars1"></div>
</div>
```

### JQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.stars1').each(function () {
                var star = jQuery(this);
                star.html("<span class='stars'>" + star.prev('.review-rating').text() + "</span>");
            });
            jQuery('.stars').stars();
        });

        jQuery.fn.stars = function() {
            return jQuery(this).each(function() {
                jQuery(this).html(jQuery("<span />").width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
            });
        }
</script>
```

behaving different in all cash..

Working fine when add JQuery in html page head tag it self but when I tried to add in Joomla custom html doesn't work at all..

When I tried at "**jsfiddle**" giving me span but with out width..

How do I add span with width.?

Jquery should return something like this

```
 "<span class="stars"><span style="width: 75.2px;"></span></span>"
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I add span with width.?

Comment: span does not have a width to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A span is an inline element and inline elements do not have fixed widths.

So your span needs the display to be set to block or inline-block.

```
span.stars span { display: inline-block; }
```

Other issue is there is no text inside the span so there is nothing to show.

---

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.stars1').each(function() {
     var star = jQuery(this);
     star.html("<span class='stars'>" + star.prev('.review-rating').text() + "</span>");
   });
   jQuery('.stars').stars();
 });

 jQuery.fn.stars = function() {
   return jQuery(this).each(function() {
     jQuery(this).html(jQuery("<span />").width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16).html("&nbsp;"));
   });
 }
```

```css
span.stars span {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ratingInfo">
  <div class="review-rating">5.0</div>
  <div class="stars1"></div>
</div>

<div class="ratingInfo">
  <div class="review-rating">4.0</div>
  <div class="stars1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: still applies, spans do not have width, selector would just need to change.

Comment: Thank You for your explanation I'm doing same thing as you did here but it doesn't work here http://jsfiddle.net/xvpphxqt/1/

Comment: because you are running the code onload and you define stars() after the place where you use it. If you move it to before or change the fiddle to run in body it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/xvpphxqt/2/